# Showing a Progress bar

Tags: android, download

I am a c++ programmer and new in android ,I am downloading text from a text file using the following method:

```
  public static String DownloadText(String URL)
    {
      int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
       InputStream in = null;
       try {
          in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
           } 
      catch (IOException e1) 
      {
        e1.printStackTrace();
         return "";
       }

    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
    int charRead;
      String str = "";
      char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];          
    try {
        while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
        {                    
            //---convert the chars to a String---
            String readString = 
                String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);                    
            str += readString;
            inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        }
        in.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return "";
    }    
    return str;        
}
```

But if it take time to download text it shows a blank screen ,I want to show a progress bar instead of the blank screen..i have seen lots of examples of progress bar but not getting any idea to implement those in my case...please help me ..

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), and put a [ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) up in the onPreExecute, do your download in doInBackground, and dismiss the dialog in onPostExecute.

Answer (score 0):

This may be helpful to you
[Issue with android layout and progressbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883537/issue-with-android-layout-and-progressbar/5884128#5884128)

Comment: Thanks for the reply jaydeep,i tried to implement http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5883537/issue-with-android-layout-and-progressbar/5884128#5884128

Comment: but getting syntex error in following lines:                                       protected  Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
             {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 //your code
               } //Syntax error on token "{", can you help me on this..thanks

Comment: instead of copying it...
write class classname extends Asynctask
{
}
then it will prompt to implement unimplemented methods..
You will get the doInBackground()method 
and please let me know if you success.. and if it give error..then what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

u can declare progress dialoge in class.
private ProgressDialog pd;
u can paste the below code in ur click event.
pd = ProgressDialog.show(context, "Please wait...", "Loading data...", true,false);
after doing the download part write
pd.dismiss();

Answer (score 0):

do the process in thread

eg

```
      new Thread(){
        public void run() {
              write the code here 

        };
    }.start();
```